# How to replace the following character with an empty space and write in next line?

Tags: c#

How to replace that character which is square in shape`(□)` with a \n or an empty space and write in next line using c#?...It is writing in text file with □... Here is my code....

```
 string line = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br>");
```

and

```
 if (line.IndexOf(line2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
    {
        if (!patternwritten)
        {
            dest.WriteLine("");
            dest.WriteLine("Pattern Name : " + line2 );
             patternwritten = true;
         }

  dest.WriteLine("LineNo : " + counter.ToString() + " : " + "" + line.TrimStart());
}
```

But it is writing the whole line with  □....Any suggestion??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that your string contains simple linefeed characters, whereas your `Environment.NewLine` value is "\r\n".

One simple way of coping with this is to perform two replacements:

```
text = text.Replace("\r\n", "<br>")
           .Replace("\n", "<br>")
```

To find our for *sure* what's going on, you should open up your file in a binary file editor and see what binary data is in the file. My guess is that you'll find a character represented by 0x0A in binary.

Comment: @Jon Skeet:LineNo : 1 :            if (textboxPath.Text != □ "")□                {□

Comment: @bala3569: Please look in a binary editor to see what's there.

Comment: @Jon Skeet:Here i dont have download permission..Is there any online binary editor there..

Comment: @Jon Skeet:2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 31 31 2F 33 30 2F 32 30 31 30 20 36 3A 34 35 3A 30 36 20 50 4D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 0D 0A 0D 0A 50 61 74 74 65 72 6E 20 4E

Comment: @bala3569: Okay, and where exactly is the square appearing?

Comment: @bala3569: But with the replacements I suggested, you shouldn't have any "0D 0A" sequences any more. They shouldn't have been replaced by `<br>`.

Comment: @Jon Skeet:The folowing code worked for me jon  dest.WriteLine(line.TrimStart().Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine).Replace("\r", Environment.NewLine));

Comment: @bala3569: But you originally wanted to replace them with `<br>` rather than with `\r\n`...

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are having problems with Unix newlines.

Try this using this method:

```
public static string ConvertToWindowsNewlines(string value)
{
    value = value.Replace("\r\n", "\n");
    value = value.Replace("\n", "\r\n");
    return value;
}
```

EDIT: Found solution in: http://dotnetperls.com/whitespace.

Contains some more tips on C# and char replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Trim()` rather than `TrimStart()`, and it will trim it off the end

Comment: That is not a problem...I want to remove that square part in that string line itself